# OpenLayers IN filter on WFS GetFeature?

Tags: openlayers, feature-filter

I'm using OpenLayers [filter module](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_filter.html) for making WFS `getFeature` requests. Already used `and`, `EqualTo` and `IsBetween`, and all of them are working fine (Example below):

```js
const featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
  srsName: 'EPSG:25830',
  featurePrefix: 'CP',
  featureTypes: ['CadastralParcel'],
  outputFormat: 'application/json',
  propertyNames: properties,
  filter: equalToFilter('id', id, false)
});
```

I found that I need to add a filter so that the features returned must have a property value IN a range of values.

Example:

```
|--------|----------|---------|
|   id   |   geom   |  year   |
|--------|----------|---------|
```

Need a filter that gets the features with the `year` field **IN** `2000`, `2010` and `2020`

I have not specifically found the filter in [the openlayers filter list](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_filter.html).

> Does this filter exist? If not, how can I implement this using the
>   existing filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't exist. You can create the same thing by combining `equalToFilter` with `or` filters.